# Making a silent installer to copy files from file to C:\Program Files\... and making shourtcut in start menu

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, silent-installer

I'm not really sure if this is the right place to ask this question.
But I want to make a script to copy the structure of installed software on the drive.
The thing is, I want to have one folder with all files that are included when the software is installed on your pc, in that folder, and then I want to copy all files from that folder to C:\Program Files... and add a shortcut to start menu.

Here is the bat code:

```
xcopy "%~dp0Struktura" "c:\" /s /i /y
cscript.exe ".\CreateLTspiceXVIIShortcut.vbs"
```

and here is the vbs code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\LTspiceXVII.lnk")
lnk.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\start_pc.exe"
lnk.Arguments = ""
lnk.Description = "LTspiceXVII"
lnk.WorkingDirectory = "%ProgramFiles%\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII"
lnk.IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles%\LTC\LTspiceXVII\\start_pc.exe, 0"
lnk.WindowStyle = "1"
lnk.Save
```

It copies all files to the right place, but it shows in cmd all process, I want to make it silent, so it won't show anything on the screen.
And after that, it doesn't make a shortcut in the start menu, which well should be made.
What should I do?

[Picture of all files I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOTpW.png)

In files "Struktura" means "structure".

[This is the content of the structure file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7iDp.png)

I hope someone understood what I meant with this.

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make everything in VBScript like:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "xcopy ""%~dp0Struktura"" ""c:\"" /s /i /y",0,True
Set lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\LTspiceXVII.lnk")
With lnk
  .TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\start_pc.exe"
  .Arguments = ""
  .Description = "LTspiceXVII"
  .WorkingDirectory = "%ProgramFiles%\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII"
  .IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles%\LTC\LTspiceXVII\start_pc.exe, 0"
  .WindowStyle = "1"
  .Save
End With
```

Then there is no need for the batch file. You can just save this as a .vbs file and execute it. It will work without any window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  with this script I get this type of error: https://imgur.com/a/RRdV4w9 I'm not sure if it is just a permission problem. Because it doesn't ask me for any permission to run the script and I don't see an option to run as administrator

Answer (score -1):

I am not a Windows user, but what I see directly:

- According https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy the parameter /q makes xcopy silent.
- It can be a problem to copy an installed software this way. E.g. Registry Entries will not be copied  or updated.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but sadly if I change **/s** for **/q** it does make it silent, but it doesn't copy files, and if I put both, it doesn't want to execute at all...¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Becuase here the `xcopy` command needs to run without window, and `/q` switch still opens a window.